# how can I modify the drivers for a specific (any) NIC?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-server-2003

I want to force one way communication only, between two computers in MS windows 2003 server OS for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it supports turning on one way communication, but if you want to change the network adapter configurations I think INetCfg is the way to go:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547694%28VS.85%29.aspx